# Using custom lodash build for Backbone in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, lodash

According to this page: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/build-differences it would seem that the `core` build of `lodash` would be enough for `Backbone 1.3.3`.

I'm using a custom build: `lodash core plus=each,sortBy,uniq,find,filter,template`

Everything seems to be working fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but not IE9. I'm getting the following errors in IE9:
`'Set' is undefined`, and `'_' is undefined`

When I use the full build of lodash (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.min.js) I don't get any errors in IE9 and everything seems to work.

What parts of lodash does IE9 need that I'm not including?